# Can't download OpenSTV anymore

Tags: support, election

I clicked on the OpenSTV link in a recent election, but all I got was the following notice on the [OpenSTV page](http://www.openstv.org/download):

> OpenSTV version 2.4.0 released February 10, 2015 Since 2003, the
>   OpenSTV project has been dedicated to improving democracy by providing
>   professional quality software for the single transferable vote and
>   other ranked-choice voting methods.
>
> OpenSTV has now been incorporated into the OpaVote online voting
>   website. All of the features of OpenSTV are now available by creating
>   a Count at OpaVote for a price of 5 cents/voter. The only difference
>   is that you need an Internet connection to use OpaVote whereas you did
>   not for OpenSTV. Since Internet connections are now available just
>   about anywhere, we are no longer supporting OpenSTV.
>
> For a limited period of time, we will be providing one-year renewals
>   for existing customers for the price of $400 per year. We will not be
>   providing OpenSTV to any new customers.
>
> OpaVote provides a better experience than OpaVote and will be less
>   expensive for most of our customers. We hope that OpaVote meets all of
>   your needs, and we apologize for any inconveniences during the
>   transition.

Does this mean that we can't download OpenSTV ourselves anymore? I always liked that we had the ability to run the elections ourselves if we wanted to. It's not essential, we have to trust SE anyway to provide good data, so it isn't really an effective way of auditing an election, but it was useful nonetheless.

Is the ability to download the OpenSTV software coming back, or is it gone for good now?