# Server error when downloading OpenSTV software using link on election pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, 500-server-error, regression

The election download OpenSTV links on an election page ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/11)) do not work and return this page:

[image]

This happens for all elections.

(A note: these links are only shown to users with the required reputation to cast votes in elections.)

Related:

- [Downloading OpenSTV doesn't work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125579/707129) (marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))
- [Can't download OpenSTV anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271673/cant-download-openstv-anymore?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C61.4714)
- [OpenSTV on election page - unavailable anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287087/openstv-on-election-page-unavailable-anymore?r=SearchResults&s=4%7C60.4287) (marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))
- [Modify message about voting data due to OpenSTV merging into OpaVote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302392/modify-message-about-voting-data-due-to-openstv-merging-into-opavote?r=SearchResults)
- [The election pages offer an outdated version of OpenSTV](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103775/the-election-pages-offer-an-outdated-version-of-openstv?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C46.4634)
- [Election application from Open STV isn't free anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244547/election-application-from-open-stv-isnt-free-anymore?r=SearchResults&s=10%7C34.7943)

Can this be fixed once and for all?

Comment: Even messier. The last openstv version that was FOSS... No one can find the source for the windows version so SE can't share it legally iirc. The ballot files for opavote still work on the last Linux build. I haven't had luck finding a working/free fork for windows either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The download links are now working

> meta elections
>
> OpenSTV download
>
> link now working fine